# Comparing records from Data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, json, dataextensions, gtl

I have a weird situation, I need to check a value in an Data Extension and if the value is not there, I need to update another data extension. But if the value is there, the data extension should not be updated.

I wrote a code, that does everything I need except comparing - It writes the data in the Data Extension no matter what the value is in the other Data extension.

Do you have any idea what I did wrong.

I need to do this using GTL and Ampscript

**My Code:**

```
    %%[
var @json, @index,  @FirstName, @LastName, @ContactName, @CompanyName, @RowCount_CompanyName, @message
set @json = '[{"CustomerID": "1657","CompanyName": "AMO Food Market","Industry": "Retail","ContactName": "Anne Mollin","ContactTitle": "Marketing Manager","Email": "anne.mollin@AMOFoodMarket.com","FullAddress": {"Address": "2732 Daver Str.","City": "Bandie","Region": "OR","PostalCode": "94215"}},{"CustomerID": "1986","CompanyName": "Folimi Tires","Industry": "Cars","ContactName": "Adrian Moods","ContactTitle": "Sales Representative","Email": "adrian.moods@folimitires.com","FullAddress": {"Address": "City Mall 100 Main St.","City": "Dondie","Region": "OR","PostalCode": "93210"}}]'
]%%


{{.datasource JSONVar type=variable maxRows = 20}}
{{.data}}
            { "target" : "@json" }
{{/data}}

CustomerID: {{CustomerID}}
            CompanyName: {{CompanyName}}
            Industry: {{Industry}}
            ContactName: {{ContactName}}
            ContactTitle: {{ContactTitle}}
            Email: {{Email}}
            ContactName: {{ContactName}}

            {{.datasource JSONAddress type=nested maxRows = 10}}
                {{.data}}
                        { "target" : "JsonVar.FullAddress" }
                {{/data}}
                        {{JSONAddress.Address}}
                        {{JSONAddress.City}}
                        {{JSONAddress.Region}}
                        {{JSONAddress.PostalCode}}       

                        %%[

                            SET @CompanyName = AttributeValue('CompanyName')

                            SET @RowCount_CompanyName = RowCount(LookupRows('CompareDE','CompanyName',@CompanyName))

                            set @ContactName = TreatAsContent('{{ContactName}}')    

                            IF @RowCount_CompanyName == 1 THEN

                            SET @message = "State is NOT in Lookup DE."

                            ELSE

                            UpsertDE("AMPscript Functions 3 - v3",1,"CustomerID", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.CustomerID}}'),"Address",TreatAsContent('{{JSONAddress.Address}}'), "City",TreatAsContent('{{JSONAddress.City}}'),"Region", TreatAsContent('{{JSONAddress.Region}}'),"PostalCode", TreatAsContent('{{JSONAddress.PostalCode}}'))

                            ENDIF

                        ]%%

            {{/datasource}}

            %%[

            SET @CompanyName = AttributeValue('CompanyName')

            SET @RowCount_CompanyName = RowCount(LookupRows('CompareDE','CompanyName',@CompanyName))

            set @ContactName = TreatAsContent('{{ContactName}}')    

            set @index = IndexOf(@ContactName,' ')
            set @FirstName = Substring(@ContactName,1,@index)
            set @LastName = Substring(@ContactName,@index,Length(@ContactName)) 

            IF @RowCount_CompanyName == 1 THEN

            SET @message = "State is NOT in Lookup DE."

            ELSE

                UpsertDE("AMPscript Functions 3 - v3",1,"CustomerID", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.CustomerID}}'), "CompanyName", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.CompanyName}}'), "Industry", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.Industry}}') , "ContactTitle", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.ContactTitle}}'), "Email", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.Email}}'),"ContactName", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.ContactName}}'), "FirstName", @FirstName, "LastName", @LastName)
                UpsertDE("CompareDE",1,"CustomerID", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.CustomerID}}'), "CompanyName", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.CompanyName}}'))

            ENDIF

            ]%%


{{/datasource}}

This email was sent by: %%Member_Busname%%, %%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%
%%profile_center_url%%
```

Comment: Before UpsertDE "AMPscript Functions 3 - v3" it should look in to "CompareDE" and search for the value of the CompanyName field, and if it is there it should skip upserting thet row. If is not ther it shoud Upsert that row in to "AMPscript Functions 3 - v3" and "CompareDE".

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `AttributeValue` as part of the lookup.

```
SET @StateName = Lookup('CompareDE','State','CompanyName',@CompanyName)
SET @StateValue = AttributeValue(@StateName)

IF @StateValue == "" THEN

   SET @message = "State is NOT in Lookup DE."

ELSE

   UpsertDE("AMPscript Functions 3 - v3",1,"CustomerID", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.CustomerID}}'), "CompanyName", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.CompanyName}}'), "Industry", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.Industry}}') , "ContactTitle", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.ContactTitle}}'), "Email", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.Email}}'),"ContactName", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.ContactName}}'), "FirstName", @FirstName, "LastName", @LastName)
   UpsertDE("CompareDE",1,"CustomerID", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.CustomerID}}'), "CompanyName", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.CompanyName}}'))

ENDIF
```

Alternatively, if you're using `LookupRows` anyway, just use that determine if `State` is null.

```
set @companyRowset = LookupRows('CompareDE','CompanyName',@CompanyName)
set @companyRowCount = RowCount(@companyRowset)

if @companyRowCount > 0 then
   set @companyRow = Row(@companyRowset, 1)
   set @StateValue = Field(@companyRow, "State")
endif

IF @StateValue == "" THEN

       SET @message = "State is NOT in Lookup DE."

    ELSE

       UpsertDE("AMPscript Functions 3 - v3",1,"CustomerID", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.CustomerID}}'), "CompanyName", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.CompanyName}}'), "Industry", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.Industry}}') , "ContactTitle", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.ContactTitle}}'), "Email", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.Email}}'),"ContactName", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.ContactName}}'), "FirstName", @FirstName, "LastName", @LastName)
       UpsertDE("CompareDE",1,"CustomerID", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.CustomerID}}'), "CompanyName", TreatAsContent('{{JSONVar.CompanyName}}'))

    ENDIF
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have more than one row for the same ***CompanyName***?
Try update your IF STATEMENT with:

```
IF @RowCount_CompanyName > 0 THEN
```

and see if this resolves the bug.